# How to use Google Snapshot Api to store app data online?

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a fighting game with many characters to unlock and I'm trying to store each user app data online so if they reinstall the app they can get their save data back again. The game saves in-game currency and some other data using `SharedPreferences` and saves the data of each character in a database using `SQLite`. Now I'm trying to use Google Snapshot Api but there are 2 problems:

- first I'm not sure how to store both of these data, I followed the documentation but I'm stuck at the part where I'm supposed to pass `byte[] bytes` to `snapshot.getSnapshotContents().writeBytes(bytes);`.
- second does this approach store the entire game data every time it's called, like every time I want to save the new amount of the in-game currency does that mean that I have to store the database again? or can it update the amount only.

Answer (score 1):

You may Refer any preferable back-end server for storing data online

- PHP with MySQL
- Firebase cloud storage
- Use Web Services in any of this language Php, .Net, Java, etc.

I personally using PHP-MySQL and Fire-base

refer Following links:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_php_mysql.htm

https://developer.android.com/studio/write/firebase

Comment: do you mean in to use the firebase realtime database?

Comment: yes Firebase provide cloud based solution for you to handling database , push notification, many more

Comment: but all of these options are paid I'd prefer if there was a free option like the google snapshot

Comment: if you need to use server to store your data then you need to pay after some use(free)

Comment: firebase also provide some free amount of space to store but afterword you need to pay as per your need